# django rest framework create json and csv api

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

i am trying to create 2 api's. 1 to access json using ajax datatable, and the other to create an export csv button.

the json api i manage to create and get the data from it using ajax, but i get problems when i try to access the api in the browser and the other to add the csv api..i will show you part of my scripts and the errors i get.

views.py

```
class VideoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DatamsVideos.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideosSerializer

    parser_classes = (CSVParser,) + tuple(api_settings.DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES)
    renderer_classes = (CSVRenderer,) + tuple(api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES)

    def list(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            vs = query_vs_by_args(**request.query_params)
            serializer = VideosSerializer(vs['items'], many=True)
            result = dict()
            result['data'] = serializer.data
            result['draw'] = vs['draw']
            result['recordsTotal'] = vs['total']
            result['recordsFiltered'] = vs['count']
            return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, template_name=None, content_type=None)

        except Exception as e:
            return Response(e, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, template_name=None, content_type=None)

    def get_renderer_context(self):
        context = super(VideoViewSet, self).get_renderer_context()
        context['header'] = (
            self.request.GET['fields'].split(',')
            if 'fields' in self.request.GET else None)
        return context

    @action(methods=['GET'], detail=False)
    def bulk_upload(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER, headers={'Location': reverse('videos-api')})
```

urls.py

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'videos', VideoViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index, name='main'),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

and this is part of my models.py

```
def query_vs_by_args(**kwargs):
    draw = int(kwargs.get('draw', None)[0])
    length = int(kwargs.get('length', None)[0])
    start = int(kwargs.get('start', None)[0])
    search_value = kwargs.get('search[value]', None)[0]
    order_column = kwargs.get('order[0][column]', None)[0]
    order = kwargs.get('order[0][dir]', None)[0]

    order_column = ORDER_VS_COLUMN_CHOICES[order_column]
    # django orm '-' -> desc
    if order == 'desc':
        order_column = '-' + order_column

    queryset = DatamsVideos.objects.all()
    total = queryset.count()

    if search_value:
        queryset = queryset.filter(Q(link__icontains=search_value) |
                                   Q(title__icontains=search_value) |
                                   Q(views__icontains=search_value) |      Q(date_added__icontains=search_value))                                         

    count = queryset.count()
    queryset = queryset.order_by(order_column)[start:start + length]
    return {
        'items': queryset,
        'count': count,
        'total': total,
        'draw': draw
    }
```

1 of the problem i have is with the function **list** from **views.py** at

```
vs = query_vs_by_args(**request.query_params)
serializer = VideosSerializer(vs['items'], many=True)
```

i still manage to get the data from it using ajax, but when i try to access the api on the browser **/main/api/videos/** it gives me this error:

```
   HTTP 404 Not Found
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: text/csv ;utf-8
Vary: Accept

""
'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Same when i try to access **/main/api/videos/?format=json**

```
TypeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'",) is not JSON serializable
```

When i try to get the csv from **/main/api/videos/?format=csv**, It Tells me **File Not Found**

I might be missing some details, can't just let me know if you want more information.

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE** 
Now i just realize if i comment the function **list** the api's works fine..but my ajax is not working anymore because i don't have the 4 necessary things for to build the json

```
    result['data'] = serializer.data
    result['draw'] = ch['draw']
    result['recordsTotal'] = ch['total']
    result['recordsFiltered'] = ch['count']
```

Comment: How do you think `int(kwargs.get('draw', None)[0])` works ?

Comment: it gets the page number, whenever i click on another page

Comment: sure, but if there's no 'draw' in the arguments, it returns None which you can't index with 0 (`None[0]` doesn't work and lead to your traceback).

Comment: i don't know to explain it but i will tell you how it works...it starts at draw = 1, when i click page 55 (example) draw it will be equal too 2, if i click previous, draw it will equal to 3, if i click show entries 100, draw it will equal to 4... and so on, whatever i do in the datatable, draw it will increase by 1...i said it wrong  when i said it "gets the page number"

Comment: for that sure, but for your CSV, it doesn't because it doesn't have all the url arguments.

Comment: oh k...i see... i did manage to change a little bit, i have split the class in views in 2 classes, 1 for the api, and 1 for the csv only, and i created 2 routes in urls.py 1 for csv and 1 for api json, it does work fine, but i still get in the api link the **TypeError ...is not JSON serializable**

Answer (score -1):

I manage to fix the csv and api problem, by separating the classes.

```
class VideoCSVExportView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DatamsPornhubVideos.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideosSerializer

    renderer_classes = (CSVRenderer,) + tuple(api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES)
```

after i create this new class for csv, i put it on a different route.

```
csv_router = DefaultRouter()
csv_router.register(r'videos', VideoCSVExportView)

...
    url(r'^csv/', include(csv_router.urls)),
..
```